# Add timeout to CDN link loading on Head tag

Tags: html, css

I am using a CDN for loading some styles. It works just fine with machines that has no proxy configured. But sometimes people can connect to the web page using proxys and the CDNs cannot be resolved, thus causing the page to have long loading times or won't load at all unless the user forces the refresh.

Is there a way to specify an attribute or something on the HTML to avoid trying to load the resources if they cannot be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's nothing native like this to stop loading a resource. Really the request should time itself out if it can't be fetched in normal cases.

Kinda hacky and there's probably a better way to solve your specific issue.

But you could try removing the link tag from your head, and insert a script instead to fetch the contents of the cdn, then dynamically append a style tag containing the contents to your head instead. Something like this

```
(function() {
  <script>
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const HOW_LONG_TO_WAIT_IN_MS = 5000;
    let loaded = false;

    fetch(URL_FOR_CDN, { signal: controller.signal })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        document.head.append(`<style>${text}</style>`);
        loaded = true;
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!loaded) controller.abort();
      }, HOW_LONG_TO_WAIT_IN_MS);
})()
</script>
```

You'll want the script to come early in your head, and this will definitely slow down loading of the page a little for all users.